# CustomValidation Attribute - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.0

I have written a CustomValidation attribute for a model I am using in an MVC application.

It's not that complex, however for some reason I am getting a really odd NullReferenceException error. I have stripped this right back to the absolute bare minimum just to try and get past this.

The code trips over here `if (value != null)`

And if I put a breakpoint on the line above it, stepping over generates the exception, almost before the breakpoint.

The weird thing is, I can take `value` and put it into a string variable and I can see it is valid and present.

I then tried to change the if statement to check that variable is null instead of `value` and that ALSO yields the error.

What have I done wrong?

The actual Error Response back from the controller is below. The line it references is the If statement.

```
<h1>An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.</h1>
        <div class="titleerror">NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</div>
        <p class="location">TechsportiseOnline.Helpers.CustomValidations&#x2B;BibValidatorAttribute.IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) in 
            <code title="C:\Users\matthew.warr\Documents\Git\Website\TechsportiseOnline\Helpers\CustomValidations.cs">CustomValidations.cs</code>, line 22
        </p>
```

**CustomAttribute Class**

```
public class BibValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        value = (string)value;

        if (value != null)
        {
            RaceEntry raceEntry = (RaceEntry)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            var _context = (ApplicationDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));

            var databaseBib = _context.RaceEntries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == raceEntry.Id).BibNumber.ToString();

            if (value == databaseBib)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("The bib number entered already exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }              
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class RaceEntry
    {

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long RaceID { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string RaceName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy}")]
        public DateTime RaceDate { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string OwnerID { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string AthleteUserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Title")]

        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name *")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name *")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        [RequiredOnlineOnly]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth *")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DateOfBirth]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Gender *")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "EA Affiliation Number")]
        public string EANumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Club Name")]
        public string Club { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Team")]
        public string Team { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Bib/Race Number")]
        [BibValidator (ErrorMessage = "The bib number you have entered already exists")]
        public string BibNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime EntryDateTime { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Phone")]
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string FullMobilePhone { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        [Display(Name = "Number")]       
        public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address *")]
        [RequiredOnlineOnly]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Town/City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "County")]
        public string County { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Postcode *")]
        [RequiredOnlineOnly]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Entry Type")]
        public string EntryType { get; set; }

        public bool Premium { get; set; }
        public bool SMSSent { get; set; }
        public bool FinalInstructionsSent { get; set; }
        public bool ResultEmailSent { get; set; }
        public bool Refunded { get; set; }
        public string StripeCode { get; set; }
        public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
        public string AmountPaidCurrency { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingName { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingAddress1 { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingAddress2 { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingCity { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingState { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingCounty { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingCountry { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingPostCode { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string BillingEmail { get; set; }

    }
```

**Relevant section of Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] RaceEntry item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            //Check bib number
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Bib number already exists");
            }
```

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like a multithreading issue. How/where is this attribute used?

Comment: Check the stack trace of the exception. Me thinks the value object in question is not an actual string object, but rather of some type that implements buggy operator overloads for == and/or !=.

Comment: Casting does not work with null values. You might want to use `value as string` instead.

Comment: @EvilTak Casting wouldn't thrown a `NullReferenceException` anyway

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, since "value" is just a method argument, it cannot be modified (i.e., set to null) by another thread, no?

Comment: @elgonzo That's not what I meant, I meant that the exception could be thrown by another thread in the same function

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, ah okay, i see, you are rather suspecting some user confusion during a debug session...

Comment: I agree with @elgonzo, it looks like a comparison/casting issue. What class or property have you added the attribute to?

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, "almost before the breakpoint." makes me think that

Comment: Saying that, what is the point of `value = (string)value;`, other than cheking it is castable to a string. After this, `value` is still of type `object`. I would create a new variable to store the string

Comment: Casting might not throw a `NullReferenceException`. It will throw an `InvalidCastException` though when `value` is anything else than a `string`. You should go with `as` here in any case

Comment: @DanielLerps You could get a `NullReferenceException`if a class implements an explicit cast operator and that throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Rhumborl That's not the case for `string` though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto https://dotnetfiddle.net/sKMoLc

Comment: I tend to agree more and more with Camilo about user confusion during debugging (probably involving an MT scenario). The question alludes to the exception happening at the line with the string cast, however the next sentence states in a contradictory manner that value can be successfully assigned to a string variable. The description in the question doesn't really add up...

Comment: The cast is more of a test to see why it was tripping over the if statement. Its being used again a model and valided using ModelState.IsValid - I'll update the question to include the model and the controller.

Comment: Can you remove everything from "if" block and check again? except return of course

Comment: @MatthewWarr, don't just throw code at us. Look at the stack trace of the exception to identify the code line throwing the exception as precisely as possible...

Comment: @elgonzo Thats what I did in the first instance, that's how I identified it was that line tripping the exception. I have now updated the question to include the error response.

Comment: @MatthewWarr, why don't you just look what line 22 in CustomValidations.cs is. Or is this a riddle for us? ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo it is the If statement as previusly mentioned.

Comment: If I remove the if statement, the exception just reports the next line.

Comment: Okay, then i guess my first comment (and assumption) seems to hold some water...

Comment: Place the following line as the first line in your IsValid method: `string thatsTheType = ReferenceEquals(value, null) ? "NULL" : value.GetType().FullName;` Then run your program in the debugger, reproduce the exception and check what the thatsTheType string is...

Comment: The data comes into the controller in the HTTP Post body as JSON. In the JSON this is a string. The JSON Deserializer then maps the matching property "BibNumber" against the model which is also of type string. Then when the attribute validates I'm not sure how it could interpret this as anything other than a string :-/

Comment: Checking that now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166105/discussion-between-matthew-warr-and-elgonzo).